# Android: ListView внутри ScrollView - нельзя. Чем заменить ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-scrollview

Везде пишут, что такое делать нельзя. Но тогда каким образом можно на андроиде реализовать такое (из моего приложения для iOS):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(текст и tableview - аналог listview для андроид, преспокойно скролятся вместе внутри одного scrollview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать LinearLayout вместо ListView

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(...);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    for (item in arrayList) {
      View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, linearLayout, false); 
      linearLayout.addView(view)
    }
```

Или с адаптером

```
    LinearLayout layout = ... 
    ListAdapter adapter = ... 

    final int adapterCount = adapter.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {
      View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
      layout.addView(item);
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView готовая библиотека

Comment: Экспериментируя, добился нужного эффекта поместив RelativeLayout в ScrollView, в который в свою очередь и вложил TextView, а ниже него ListView. Теперь проблема в другом - ListView не реагирует на height=wrap content. Всегда одна строка.

Comment: ListView без костыля работать внутри ScrollView не будет да и не комильфо это. Легче использовать LinearLayout с адаптером как в примере выше

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас в `ScrollView` находится что-то сверху, а всё остальное - `ListView`, то самым простым решением будет:

1. Поместить всё, что выше `ListView` в отдельный `layout` файл.
2. Убрать `ScrollView`.
3. Поместить разметку из п.1 в `ListView` методом `addHeader(View v)` класса `ListView`.

Итого:никакого шаманства с библиотеками, переопределениями клсассов, измерениями разметки в рантайме и минимум изменений в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```